# webshot/phantom pdf, printing only second half of the page

Tags: node.js, pdf, meteor, phantomjs

I'm working with webshot npm module to create pdf file of my page

This is my page
[image]

and

I'm getting this as output in pdf

[image]

my settings are

```
    var options = {
                  renderDelay:10000,
                    "paperSize": {
                        "format": "Letter", 
                        "orientation": "portrait", 
                        "border": "1cm"
                    },
                    shotSize: {
                        width: 'all',
                        height: 'all'
                    },
                    shotOffset: {
                        left: 0
                        , right: 0
                        , top: 0
                        , bottom: 0
                    }
                };

                webshot(url, fileName, options, function(err) {
                  fs.readFile(fileName, function (err,data) {
                    if (err) {
                      return console.log(err);
                    }

                    fs.unlinkSync(fileName);
                    fut.return(data);
                  });
                });

            this.response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',"Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename=generated.pdf"});
this.response.end(fut.wait());
```

For meteor guys this is my server side root

```
this.route('generatePDF', {
        path: '/api/generatePDF',
        where: 'server',
        action: function() {
            var webshot = Meteor.npmRequire('webshot');
            var fs      = Npm.require('fs');
            Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');
            var fut = new Future();
            var fileName = "generated_"+Random.id()+".pdf";
            var userid = (Meteor.isClient) ? Meteor.userId() : this.userId;
            console.log(userid);
            // var username = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: userid}).username;
            var url = "url";

            var options = {
              renderDelay:10000,
                "paperSize": {
                    "format": "Letter", 
                    "orientation": "portrait", 
                    "border": "1cm"
                },
                shotSize: {
                    width: 'all',
                    height: 'all'
                },
                shotOffset: {
                    left: 0
                    , right: 0
                    , top: 0
                    , bottom: 0
                }
            };

            webshot(url, fileName, options, function(err) {
              fs.readFile(fileName, function (err,data) {
                if (err) {
                  return console.log(err);
                }

                fs.unlinkSync(fileName);
                fut.return(data);
              });
            });

            this.response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',"Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename=generated.pdf"});
            this.response.end(fut.wait());
        }
    });
```

Am I missing anything here? Any help appreciated

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. Perhaps the site, PhantomJS or both are broken. Maybe there is a workaround by changing the shotOffset

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change paperSize to:

```
"paperSize": {
                width: '612px',
                height: '792px',
                margin: 'XXpx'
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else will have trouble with that - I had the same issue. I am not able to tell you exactly why, but the problem was that I was using bootstrap and the wrapper of my page had the "container" class. After removing this class the whole page was rendered - without removing it it just rendered around the half of the page.